# MVC 5 user data available on all pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Basically I need user data to be available on all pages in the site.
I need to display some user properties in the layout, like:

> [Username], [FirstName], [LastName], [Email], [IsEmailVerified],
>   [Phone], [LastLoginDate], and 4 more properties...

But, these aspects need to be considered:

1. No use of Session (I disabled it in my application).
2. No database interaction on each request in order to get those user properties - I want to get them properties once and store them somewhere available.
3. I use Forms Authentication.

Now, from a little search I made, I found this article from 2008, posted by Microsoft, about Forms Authentication: [Storing Additional User Data in the Ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-cs#step-4-storing-additional-user-data-in-the-ticket), and [Using a Custom Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-cs#step-5-using-a-custom-principal).

I think this is the closest approach, because now I use **User.Identity.Name** to get only the [Username] stored in the authentication ticket, and I love using it because it is quick, available and simple.

**But** I also have a few questions that bother me with this approach:

1. This was posted in 2008, is it still relevant for 2017? is there something better and new today?
2. As you can see above, I have quite a bit user properties that need to go into the auth cookie, and as I read - a lot of user data in the auth cookie is not reccomended...

Thanks for the helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's still valid. Although people will tell you that newer approaches exists that involve claims and you should possibly considef the new Identity subsystem, the old good forms authentication is still one of viable options.

As for "lot of data", it's just one of shortcommings of the forms module, it doesn't handle multiple cookies, thus, you are constrained by the 4kb limit of a single cookie. Considering the encryption and signing, this makes much less data available in the custom data section of the cookie. But still, it should still be enough to have a simple serialization of like 10 attributes.

If you want to make a half of a step forward, you can just switch to the session authentication module, a benefit is that it is based on claims plus it supports large user data (as it automatically splits the data into chunks). I've blogged on that some time ago

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2014/11/forms-authentication-revisited-for-net.html

A snippet from this approach

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity( "custom" );
identity.AddClaim( new Claim( ClaimTypes.Name, txtLogin.Text ) );

var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal( identity );

principal.AddClaim( new Claim( ClaimTypes.UserData, "whatever goes here" ) );

SessionAuthenticationModule sam =    
      FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
var token = 
sam.CreateSessionSecurityToken( principal, string.Empty, 
     DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(), DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20).ToUniversalTime(), false );

sam.WriteSessionTokenToCookie( token );
```

Comment: The SessionAuthenticationModule sounds interesting... I understand it uses the Forms Authentication in the background? And it is not related to Session somehow though it's called SessionAuthenticationModule?

Comment: It doesn't use forms auth in the background, it replaces the forms module. And no, it's not related to "sessions" you think about. Identity 2.0 uses the module, too, in fact you could have heard of it under the name WIF (SessionAuthenticationModule and WSFederationAuthenticationModule are both part of WIF).

Comment: Ok, and how do you reach those claims (user data)? via "User.Identity.{claim}"? Also, is there any shortcoming using WIF?

Comment: Yes,my you just cast `User.Identity` to `ClaimsIdentity` and you have the `Claims` property. Also, there are no shortcomings you should be afraid of, as I said, Identity 2.0 uses WIF internally, meaning, most of current auth is done this way. I just show you a lower level approach.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much. But one last question about this approach in general (storing the user entity in the hard disk of the user)... I think there's a problem when the user updates a property in the database, do you update the auth cookie with the new values when the user updates his properties?

Comment: Ok, this is fine, but if a user is logged on several devices (persistent), for example laptop and mobile, on each device the user entity is stored in the hard disk, if the user updates his data in mobile, the auth cookie in the mobile device gets updated, but the laptop is still authenticated with the old version of the user data... how can I solve this?

Comment: That's another question, not related to this one.

Comment: Ok, and I read that WIF is also obsolete, and the new player is the OWIN in asp.net core...

Comment: OWIN is not related to identity management, it's a general term for middleware architecture in asp.net core. The identity subsystem is called just Identity. Some people add OWIN there so they refer to OWIN Identity but you can't shorten it to just OWIN.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Finally, I decided to stay with Forms Authentication, and cache the user data on server side...